# Iterating on data in two 3D arrays python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, append

I'm trying to perform a number of functions to get some results from a set of satellite imagery (in the example case I am performing similarity functions). I first intended to iterate through all the pixels simultaneously,  each containing 4 numbers, then calculating a value for each one based off these too numbers then write it to an array e.g scipy.spatial.distance.correlation(pixels_0, pixels_1).

The issue I have is when I run this loop I am having issues getting it to save to an array 1000x1000 giving it a value for each pixel.

```
array_0 = # some array with dimensions(1000, 1000, 4)
array_1 = # some array with dimensions(1000, 1000, 4)

result_array = []

for rows_0, rows_1 in itertools.izip(array_0, array_1):
    for pixels_0, pixels_1 in itertools.izip(rows_0, rows_1):
        results = some_function(pixels_0, pixels_1)
        print results
        >>> # successfully prints desired results
        results_array.append(results)
        >>> # unsuccessful in creating the desired array
```

I am getting the results I want to get printing down the run window but I don't know how to put it back into an array which I could manipulate in a similar manor. Are my for loops the issue or is this a simple issue with appending it back to arrays? Any explanation on speeding it up would also be great too as I'm very new to python and programming all together.

```
a = np.random.rand(10, 10, 4)
b = np.random.rand(10, 10, 4)

def dotprod(T0, T1):
    return np.dot(T0, T1)/(np.linalg.norm(T0)*np.linalg.norm(T1))

results =dotprod(a.flatten(), b.flatten())
results = results.reshape(a.shape)
```

This now causes ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged,
and when printing the first results value I receive only one number. Is this the fault of my own poorly constructed function or in how I am using numpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use `Numpy` for your task. You should think in vectors. And you should write your `some_function()`to work in a vectorized manner.  Here is an example:

```
array_0 = np.random.rand(1000,1000,4)
array_1 = np.random.rand(1000,1000,4)
results = some_function(array_0.flatten(), array_1.flatten()) ## this will be (1000*1000*4 X 1)
results = results.reshape(array_0.shape)   ## reshaping to make it the way you want it.
```

Comment: I like the vector way of thinking since one of the operations is to find the angle between the two vectors: I wrote a simple function for it def 'dotprod(T0, T1):'
    'return np.dot(T0, T1)/(np.linalg.norm(T0)*np.linalg.norm(T1))'   and replaces the 'some_function' but the output is a single number rather than in an array. Is this about redoing the function rather than the way you go through the numbers in the data set?

Answer (score 0):

Before investing anymore effort into programming it this way, take a look into the numpy package. It will be many times faster!

About your code: shouldn't your results array also be multidimensional? So in your inner (per row) loop you should be appending to a row, which you then in you outer loop append to your results matrix.

Try it with a small amount of data (e.g. 10 x 10 x 4) to learn from, but after that switch to numpy as soon as you can...

Comment: Yes I intend to have a 1000x1000 with all the values in after perfoming my functions. This may sound like a silly question but when you mention switching to numpy what exactly do you mean? I believe my data is in numpy arrays at the moment, and how would I structure it to benefit from numpy as most as possible?